# classification report in machine learning sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 1]
target_names = ['class 0', 'class 1', 'class 2']
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

    class 0       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
    **class 1       0.00      0.00      0.00         1**
    class 2       1.00      0.67      0.80         3

avg / total       0.70      0.60      0.61         5
```

why the class1 having a score of 0.0 in all cases, even it has support! and why it hasn't involved int prediction

Comment: Did you read [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#classification-report)?

Answer (score 1):

The support is the number of samples of the true response that lie in that class. So, in your `y_true` you have 1 class0, 1 class 1, and 3 class 2. **All the class that appear in you y_true, will appear in the classification_report**.

Check definitions of precision and recall. If you don't guess correctly any value for one class, this same class will have precision and recall equal to 0, since there isn't any True Positive.

So the output is correct.

Comment: class 1       0.00      0.00      0.00         1,  does it make any impact on future predictions ;
if suppose, my model accuracy 0.67 and it contain that class, what impact does it posses on future predictions

Comment: With this output, you can say that you will probably (it depends on future data) have problems classifying class1.  You have to understand what is precision and recall.